# React Native Fetch video file by chunk / YouTube Data API chunk(multipart) upload

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, youtube-data-api

I made a YouTube API upload app. It works great with small video file sizes but with larger sizes my app crashes. The exception happens when I try to get the video file with `Fetch()`.

**Question: Is there a way I can fetch a large file in React Native and feed it into the YouTube API in smaller chunks?**

Here is my fetch code:

```
const fetchResponse = await fetch(videoUri);    
const blob = await fetchResponse.blob();  
var file = new File([blob], "video.mp4", {type: "video/mp4"});
```

My upload YouTube code is taken from the following git repos - supposedly supports multipart upload as well:
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/cors_upload.js and
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/upload_video.js

Here is my full upload code:

```
uploadVideo = async function() {  
        var match = this.state.match.value;

        var video = match.mergedVideo;
  
        var players = match.players;
      
        var scoreboard = this.state.match.value.scoreboard;
        var points = match.points;
  
        var title = players[0].name + " vs. " + players[1].name + " " + scoreboard;            
        var description = this.descriptionBuilder(points, match.videos);

        /*const fetchResponse = await fetch(video);    
        const blob = await fetchResponse.blob();  
        var file = new File([blob], "video.mp4", {type: "video/mp4"});
        console.log(file);*/

        const file = await DocumentPicker.pick({
          type: [DocumentPicker.types.video],
         });

        var metadata = {
          snippet: {
            title: title,
            description: description,
            tags: ['youtube-cors-upload'],
            categoryId: 22
          },
          status: {
            privacyStatus: 'unlisted'
          }
        };

        var uploader = new MediaUploader({
          baseUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos',
          file: file,
          token: this.state.user.auth.accessToken,
          metadata: metadata,
          chunkSize: 1024 * 1024,
          params: {
            part: Object.keys(metadata).join(',')
          },
          onError: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var message = data;
            try {
            var errorResponse = JSON.parse(data);
            message = errorResponse.error.message;
            } finally {
            alert(message);
            }
          }.bind(this),
          onProgress: function(data) {
            var currentTime = Date.now();
            var bytesUploaded = data.loaded;
            var totalBytes = data.total;
            var bytesPerSecond = bytesUploaded / ((currentTime - window.uploadStartTime) / 1000);
            var estimatedSecondsRemaining = (totalBytes - bytesUploaded) / bytesPerSecond;
            var percentageComplete = (bytesUploaded * 100) / totalBytes;
            this.setState({ youtubeUploadProgress:  percentageComplete / 100});
    
            console.log("Uploaded: " + bytesUploaded + " | Total: " + totalBytes + " | Percentage: " + percentageComplete + " | Esitmated seconds remaining: " + estimatedSecondsRemaining);        
          }.bind(this),
          onComplete: function(data) {
            console.log("Complete");
            alert("Upload successful!");
            this.setState({ youtubeUploadProgress:  0});
          }.bind(this)
        });
    
        window.uploadStartTime = Date.now();
        uploader.upload();
      }
```

and this is my `cors_upload.js` in React Native class module:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MediaUploader extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const obj = this;    
        const DRIVE_UPLOAD_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/';    

        var options = props;

        var noop = function() {};
        this.file = options.file;
        this.contentType = options.contentType || this.file.type || 'application/octet-stream';
        this.metadata = options.metadata || {
            'title': this.file.name,
            'mimeType': this.contentType
        };
        this.token = options.token;
        this.onComplete = options.onComplete || noop;
        this.onProgress = options.onProgress || noop;
        this.onError = options.onError || noop;
        this.offset = options.offset || 0;
        this.chunkSize = options.chunkSize || 0;
        //this.retryHandler = new RetryHandler();
        //this.retryHandler = new obj.RetryHandler();
        this.interval = 1000; // Start at one second
        this.maxInterval = 60 * 1000;

        this.url = options.url;
        if (!this.url) {
            var params = options.params || {};
            params.uploadType = 'resumable';
            //this.url = this.buildUrl_(options.fileId, params, options.baseUrl);
            this.url = obj.buildUrl_(options.fileId, params, options.baseUrl);
        }
        this.httpMethod = options.fileId ? 'PUT' : 'POST';               
    }

    retry = function(fn) {
        setTimeout(fn, this.interval);
        this.interval = this.nextInterval_();
    };

    reset = function() {
        this.interval = 1000;
    };

    nextInterval_ = function() {
        var interval = this.interval * 2 + this.getRandomInt_(0, 1000);
        return Math.min(interval, this.maxInterval);
    };

    getRandomInt_ = function(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    };

    buildQuery_ = function(params) {
        params = params || {};
        return Object.keys(params).map(function(key) {
            return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
        }).join('&');
    };

    buildUrl_ = function(id, params, baseUrl) {
        var url = baseUrl || DRIVE_UPLOAD_URL;
        if (id) {
            url += id;
        }
        var query = this.buildQuery_(params);
        if (query) {
            url += '?' + query;
        }
        return url;
    }; 

    upload = function() {
        //var self = this;
        console.log("UPLOAD called", this.file.size);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        xhr.open(this.httpMethod, this.url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Length', this.file.size);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Type', this.contentType);
    
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            console.log("ON LOAD CALLED");
            if (e.target.status < 400) {
            var location = e.target.getResponseHeader('Location');
            this.url = location;
            this.sendFile_();
            } else {
            this.onUploadError_(e);
            }
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.onerror = this.onUploadError_.bind(this);
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(this.metadata));
    };

    sendFile_ = function() {
        console.log("SEND FILE CALLED");
        var content = this.file;        
        var end = this.file.size;
    
        if (this.offset || this.chunkSize) {
            // Only bother to slice the file if we're either resuming or uploading in chunks
            if (this.chunkSize) {
            end = Math.min(this.offset + this.chunkSize, this.file.size);
            }
            content = content.slice(this.offset, end);
        }
    
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('PUT', this.url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', this.contentType);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', 'bytes ' + this.offset + '-' + (end - 1) + '/' + this.file.size);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Type', this.file.type);
        if (xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', this.onProgress);
        }
        xhr.onload = this.onContentUploadSuccess_.bind(this);
        xhr.onerror = this.onContentUploadError_.bind(this);
        xhr.send(content);        
    };

    resume_ = function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('PUT', this.url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Range', 'bytes */' + this.file.size);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Upload-Content-Type', this.file.type);
        if (xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', this.onProgress);
        }
        xhr.onload = this.onContentUploadSuccess_.bind(this);
        xhr.onerror = this.onContentUploadError_.bind(this);
        xhr.send();
    };

    extractRange_ = function(xhr) {
        var range = xhr.getResponseHeader('Range');
        if (range) {
            this.offset = parseInt(range.match(/\d+/g).pop(), 10) + 1;
        }
    };

    onContentUploadSuccess_ = function(e) {
        if (e.target.status == 200 || e.target.status == 201) {
            this.onComplete(e.target.response);
        } else if (e.target.status == 308) {
            this.extractRange_(e.target);
            this.reset();
            this.sendFile_();
        }
    };

    onContentUploadError_ = function(e) {
        if (e.target.status && e.target.status < 500) {
            this.onError(e.target.response);
        } else {
            this.retry(this.resume_.bind(this));
        }
    };

    onUploadError_ = function(e) {
        this.onError(e.target.response); // TODO - Retries for initial upload
    };

}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

To avoid using `Fetch()` I decided to use `React Native Document Picker`. Now I can select the video file and pass it to the `MediaUploader` following this guide: https://alishavineeth.medium.com/upload-a-video-from-a-mobile-device-to-youtube-using-react-native-eb2fa54a7445

Now if I set the `chunkSize` option I will receive a `.slice` array exception because the object structure doesn't match. If I pass the `file` without the `chunkSize` option the `metadata` uploads to YouTube but the video status will be stuck on `processing` without any other errors. The video upload process never begins.

DocumentPicker responds with the following object after I select my file:

```
[{"fileCopyUri": "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A7853", "name": "video_1629795128339.mp4", "size": 192660773, "type": "video/mp4", "uri": "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A7853"}]
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Managed to fix my `DocumentPicker` file issue(from my Update 1) with changing `React Native Document Picker` to `Expo Document Picker`.

Now I am able to select large files and call the upload function - the metadata uploads, the video file begins to upload as well but the app crashes during the upload. If I set the `chunkSize` option on the `MediaUploader` object I get `[TypeError: content.slice is not a function. (In 'content.slice(this.offset, end)', 'content.slice' is undefined)]`

Expo Document Picker responds with the following object after I select my video file:

```
{"name": "video_1629801588164.mp4", "size": 5799179, "type": "video/mp4", "uri": "file:///data/user/0/com.tennis.rec/cache/DocumentPicker/8b350fbf-1b66-4a78-a10f-b61eb2ed3032.mp4"}
```

**UPDATE 3 - RESOLVED!!!**

The chunk upload is working now!!! I modified my `cors_upload.js` file where the `chunkSize` is being evaluated and sliced with the following code:

```
if (this.offset || this.chunkSize) {
            // Only bother to slice the file if we're either resuming or uploading in chunks
            if (this.chunkSize) {
            end = Math.min(this.offset + this.chunkSize, this.file.size);
            }
            console.log("CONTENT SLICE", this.offset, end, this.file.size);
            //content = content.slice(this.offset, end);
            var base64 = await RNFS.read(this.file.uri, this.chunkSize, this.offset, 'base64');
            content = Uint8Array.from(atob(base64), c => c.charCodeAt(0));
        }
```

I added `React Native File System` and I am using its `read()` function to load the chunk as `base64` and convert it back to a byte array.

Comment: Why is that you're not addapting [`cors_upload.js`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/cors_upload.js); that code implements uploading a file in chunks (as per the official specification: [Resumable Uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol)).

Comment: @stvar I added my MediaUploader class (cors_upload.js). This upload works with small video file size without any issues.

Comment: My issues is at loading the video file before passing to the MediaUploader object. React Native keeps loading it fully into the memory. I can't pass just a video URI to MediaUploader - I need the video file as a File object.

Comment: Why don't you use the option `chunkSize` of `MediaUploader`? Employing it wouldn't load your video in memory in its entirety, but, successively, only `chunckSize` of it, while passing over those chunks to YouTube Data API.

Comment: @stvar I added `chunkSize: 1024 * 1024` to the options but how do I pass my video to the `file` option? If I pass my file URI to the file option only the metadata uploads to YouTube. The file option requires a File object.

Comment: I also tried using this [guide](https://alishavineeth.medium.com/upload-a-video-from-a-mobile-device-to-youtube-using-react-native-eb2fa54a7445) with no luck.When I pass the file from the DocumentPicker only the metadata uploads to YouTube and the video file gets stuck on `processing`.

Comment: if I set the `chunkSize` option I get the following exception: `[TypeError: content.slice is not a function. (In 'content.slice(this.offset, end)', 'content.slice' is undefined)]`